# connecting slick 3.1.1 to the database

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following code and I'm trying to connect to the MySQL database without success.

cat Database.scala

```
package com.github.odnanref.EmailFilter

import slick.driver.MySQLDriver._
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.backend.Database

/**
  * Created by andref on 12/05/16.
  */
class Database {
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/playdb"
  val db = Database.forURL(url, driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

  override def finalize() {
    db.close()

    super.finalize()
  }
}
```

cat EmailMessageTable.scala

```
package com.github.odnanref.EmailFilter

import java.sql.Timestamp

import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

import scala.concurrent.Future

class EmailMessageTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[EmailMessage](tag, "email_message") {

  def id      = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  def email   = column[String]("email")
  def subject = column[String]("subject")
  def body    = column[String]("body")
  def datain  = column[Timestamp]("datain")
  def email_id= column[Long]("email_id")

  def * = (id, email, subject, body, datain, email_id) <> ((EmailMessage.apply _).tupled, EmailMessage.unapply)
  def ? = (id.get.?, email.?, subject.?, body.?, datain.?).shaped.<>({ r =>; _1.map(_ =>
    EmailMessage.tupled((_1, _2.get, _3.get, _4.get, _5.get))) }, (_: Any) =>
    throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))
}
```

I can't initialize the database and execute search query's or insert statements based on this code I try to do

```
val db = new Database()
db.db.run(TableQuery[EmailMessageTable] += EmailMessage(...) )
And it says, it doesn't know the method +=
```

Also I get this error:

```
Database.scala:4: imported `Database' is permanently hidden by definition of class Database in package EmailFilter
[warn] import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.backend.Database
```

What am I doing wrong?

Post EDIT>

```
package com.github.odnanref.EmailFilter

import java.sql.Timestamp


case class EmailMessage(
  id: Option[Long], 
  email: String, 
  subject:String,
  body:String,
  datain: Timestamp,
  email_id: Long
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing a class named `Database` inside a file that defines another class with the same name. You can:

- rename your `Database` class:

  ```
  class MyDatabase {
   val url = ...
   val db = ...
   ...
  }
  ```
- rename imported class:

  ```
  import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.backend.{Database => SlickDB}
  ...
  val db = SlickDB.forURL(url, driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  ```
- avoid importing `Database` explicitly:

  ```
  import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.backend
  ...
  val db = backend.Database.forURL(url, driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  ```

Comment: Awsome, that solved an issue, what about the += 
value += is not a member of slick.lifted.TableQuery[com.github.odnanref.EmailFilter.EmailMessageTable]

Comment: Could you edit your question and post your `EmailMessage` case class definition?

Comment: It looks like the file that contains `db.run` invocation is missing an import:
`import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._`

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Forgot that I was calling the run method outside the other object.